# Fill in small 'islands' with surrounding raster pixel values

Tags: qgis, raster

I have a raster of a land classification with about 8 land classes.  I want to clean it up a bit by converting any isolated small groups of pixels e.g. 4 pixels of one value surrounded by pixels of another value - change value A to value B.

Is this possible as a tool or plugin in QGIS?

For example, in the image the final result would be solid green to the left, solid red to the right and blue patches at the top and bottom (because they are larger than a predetermined area, say 4 pixels)

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can give the [SAGA processing tool "Majority Filter"](https://saga-gis.sourceforge.io/saga_tool_doc/2.2.0/grid_filter_6.html) from the processing toolbox a try.

Example before:

[image]

Example after (default settings used):

[image]

Answer (score 7):

As answered by @MrXsquared, SAGA handles it efficiently in a much simpler way. Alternatively, another way to achieve this in QGIS version 3.x is:

1. Make sure `GRASS 7` plugin is installed.
2. From `Processing` > `Toolbox` > Search for  `r.neighbors`
3. In the `r.neighbors` window, select the raster layer from the dropdown menu.
4. Set the `Neighborhood Operation` to `mode`
5. Set the `Neighborhood Size` to the desired filter size (e.g. 4) and click `Run`

A way to get this working in older QGIS version(v2.x):

1. Make sure `Raster Terrain Analysis` plugin is installed.
2. Open Raster calculater in QGIS to apply a majority filter. In QGIS Go to `"Raster" > "Raster Analysis" > "Raster Calculator"`or simply `"Raster" > "Raster Calculator"` (based on your QGIS version) and under expression section to apply a 4x4 `Majority Filter` to the raster, use the below expression:

   `con(majority_filter(rastername, 4, 4), rastername, nodata())`

Similarly in ArcGIS you can use `"Majority Filter"` tool, which is located in the "Spatial Analyst" toolbox which basically does the same thing by specifying the input layer, kernel size, and the output file name.

Comment: Are you sure this is correct? In QGIS, raster calculator is just under `Raster` (no `.. / Raster Analysis`) and both `majority_filter` and `con` give me syntax errors, and I cannot find either in the docs. Wouldn't be the first time there's super undocumented functionality but just checking...

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, my knowledge of this comes from QGIS version 2.14.5 (I know it's pretty old, but i primarily use ArcGIS and use QGIS occassionally where ArcGIS fails). My machine has 'Raster Terrain Analysis' plugin installed which is responsible for the majority_filter expression to work correctly in Raster calculator which I realise is no longer available in QGIS 3x. Luckily there are other ways to get this done in 3.x so I have edited my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 5):

The gdal_sieve utility https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_sieve.html is made for this purpose.

> **gdal_sieve.py** script removes raster polygons smaller than a provided
> threshold size (in pixels) and replaces them with the pixel value of
> the largest neighbour polygon. The result can be written back to the
> existing raster band, or copied into a new file.